# set cursor position in cell in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, cursor, cell

There are many questions and answers on how to set the cursor to a specific cell of a datagridview.

My question goes a bit further - how to set the cursor in a specific place (for instance at the end of the text) inside a cell in datagridview?

in the keyup event I have the following code

```
If (e.Alt AndAlso (e.KeyCode = Keys.I)) Then
        dgvScript.Rows(dgvScript.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = "Slugline"
        dgvScript.Rows(dgvScript.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
        dgvScript.Rows(dgvScript.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = "INT."


        dgvScript.BeginEdit(True)
End If
```

So basically when a user presses ALT+I the 2nd column will get the value "INT."
I want the user to be able to immediately start typing after "INT." without first having to press END to get to the end of the text in the cell.

any ideas on how to go about this in a simple manner?
thanks!

just corrected a piece of zombie code pointed out by one of the contributors! thx jmcilhinney

Comment: How does this make sense: `dgvScript.CurrentCell = dgvScript.CurrentCell`?

Comment: yeah -- never mind that!  :) LOL